# SDPTools package for maple?

Tags: maple

Im looking for the "SDPTools" package in Maple. Its mentioned here;

https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.6382

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you possibly looking for the Dynamic Systems package? The SDPTools package is not in public domain, you can try to write to the developers at fguo@mmrc.iss.ac.cn

```
with(DynamicSystems);
[AlgEquation, AppendConnect, BodePlot, CharacteristicPolynomial, Chirp, Coefficients, ControllabilityMatrix, Controllable, Covariance, DTF2DDE, DiffEquation, DiscretePlot, EquilibriumPoint, FeedbackConnect, FrequencyResponse, FrequencyResponseSystem, GainMargin, Grammians, ImpulseResponse, ImpulseResponsePlot, IsSystem, Linearize, MagnitudePlot, NewSystem, NicholsPlot, NormH2, NormHinf, NyquistPlot, ObservabilityMatrix, Observable, ParallelConnect, PhaseMargin, PhasePlot, PrintSystem, Ramp, Resample, ResponsePlot, RootContourPlot, RootLocusPlot, RouthTable, SSModelReduction, SSTransformation, ScaleInputs, ScaleOutputs, SeriesConnect, Simulate, Sinc, Sine, Square, StateSpace, Step, StepProperties, Subsystem, System, SystemConnect, SystemOptions, ToContinuous, ToDiscrete, Tools, TransferFunction, Triangle, Verify, ZeroPoleGain, ZeroPolePlot]
```

Comment: I am trying to do some convex optimization on a polynomail in several variables using the semdefinite programming approch/package. Ill take a look at this Dyn. Sys. package tho.